# Why Elasticsearch Autoscaling does not support scale in?

Tags: elasticsearch, autoscaling

I cannot find any description about ASG scale-in in the official document.

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/autoscaling-apis.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-autoscaling.html

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

But the answer, as of now, it's just... (effectively) doesn't.

And we weren't able to squeeze a comprehensive explanation "why" out of our Elastic support.

Maybe it's because they charge by volume on their cloud SaaS.

Or maybe because it's just being overlooked/neglected as this is obviously a *lower* priority feature than scaling up (your cluster would have no problem to survive with extra space/capacity, the opposite is not true).

To the latter point, they have certain other cluster maintenance, ehm, *things* that's been around for years & are still there.
For instance, their volume balancing is extremely crappy, so we HAVE TO run our own rebalance script to keep it healthy.

Hopefully, things would get dramatically better when their serverless initiative would roll out.
Until then, I bet we have to just live with it.

Answer (score 1):

As Yuri hinted it may be that their financial interests in 'Elasticsearch Service' (their SaaS offering) is one unfortunate motivation for them *not* to do this.

In [its documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-autoscaling.html) it says (emphasis added):

> Autoscaling based on memory or CPU, as well as **autoscaling downward**, is not currently supported. In case you want to adjust the size of your data tier to add more memory or CPU, or in case you deleted data and want to scale it down, you can set the current size per zone of each data tier manually.

Implementing this would likely reduce their revenue stream, from all the people who have stacks that have autoscaled *up* but are now overprovisioned.

Currently the only way to manage this automatically is probably to write your own monitoring which calls the [Elasticsearch Service RESTful API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-restful-api.html) to find under-utilised nodes - I haven't done this (yet) but the [Deployment - Info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/Deployment_-_Info.html#get-deployment-es-resource-info) bit of the API looks like a good place to start poking.